# Experiments to the question : why wet is dark?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

> How can we prove the explanations for: why clothes get dark when they are wet, by experiments?

Comment: Coat a piece of cloth with varnish.  Let it dry.

Comment: Related question: [Why wet is dark](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30366/50583). Obligatory comment: Physical explanations are never *proven*, "only" *not falsified*.

Comment: I guess you learn something new everyday. Thanks @ACuriousMind!

Answer (score 3):

If "wet" causes the material to become less scattering, and thus darker, because of a smaller change in refractive index between the fibers and the liquid, then the experiment to do would be to change the refractive index of the liquid. If you can see a change in "darkness" as a function of refractive index (making sure to correct for surface reflection effects) this supports the explanation - you could also look for a change in the "lightness" in transmission, as Georg pointed out (and as I mentioned in [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159079/26969). However, as ACuriousMind pointed out - you can't *prove* that it is the right explanation. You can only ever say "I still haven't disproved it".

Comment: +1 yes, that's what I would do. As Georg points out, you could also measure light transmission as by definition light that is transmitted is not reflected.