# Model of scattering in wet things

Tags: optics, everyday-life, scattering, reflection, refraction

You know that clothes and some surfaces become darker when wet (covered in an earlier question: [why wet is dark](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/why-wet-is-dark)?), because of the disordered reflections or of the refractive index of water or something else.

I have a related question:

We have scattering in clothes when they are dry and when they get wet, they get darker - is this because of less scattering, or more?

Can you explain how it depends on the scattering & tell me the relevant formulas for answering this question when the clothes get wet with brine (Salt-water or something else that has different refractive index and reflective index )?

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159056/26969

Comment: It wasn't same as my question . Answer my question:

Comment: @MichaeleCastle Floris is pointing you to a *related* question which you might find useful.  You should refrain from making demands of the people who freely donate their time to try and help you.